# What is the equivalent of RPC in new Unity Networking?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, rpc, multiplayer, unity-networking

Unity has upgraded its Networking system and called the old one as legacy networking.

So how do we change our RPC calls into the new Unity Networking? 
What is the equivalent of this approach? 
Should we write our own methods for it? (Sending byte arrays etc.)

Comment: Regarding the infuriating job of changing from old RPCs, to Unity's "new" networking.  **The following question, has a full explanation of precisely how to do it.**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381964/making-direct-rpc-style-calls-in-new-unity-networking

Comment: Actually this one is also very useful!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371989/unity-networkmanager-component-ip-for-lan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ClientRpc]` is the equivalent in the new Networking system.

See here for more information - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html

---

*In response to your comment:*

Exactly. You `[Command]` from clients up to the server and `[ClientRpc]` from the server down to all clients.

In addition, you can send messages to individual clients using the `Send()` function on the `connectionToClient` of a `NetworkBehaviour`.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkConnection.Send.html

Comment: *except* that is only Server-To-Client, not like photonView.RPC() which would could be called from a client. To convert photon code you would need to change photonView.RPC("blah") to CmdBlah() which would call on a server [Command]CmdBlah( ) { RpcBlah(); } which would then call [ClientRpc] RpcBlah() on all clients (including the original caller).

Comment: Again, for anyone googling here, the following question is very useful:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381964/making-direct-rpc-style-calls-in-new-unity-networking