# Making "direct" RPC style calls in new Unity networking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

Say you have

[image]

Using "new" Unity networking, you must have *(as far as I know)* a `NetworkManager` somewhere. It will spawn the ridiculous "player" object.

The ridiculous "player" object must have a class which inherits from `NetworkBehaviour`.

Most teams call that class something like "Comms" or "AbstractPlayer" or "Junction".

```
public class Comms : NetworkBehaviour { }
```

So, every command (like "Jump") has to be mediated by that "Comms" class.

For each command (like "Jump") **you need a pair of functions** in the Comms class:

```
public class Comms : NetworkBehaviour {

    // for every command (say, "Jump") you need THIS PAIR of functions:

    public void CommandJump() {
        Debug.Log("this is comms - client, do a Jump");
        CmdJump();
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdJump() {
        Debug.Log("this is comms - server. a Jump arrived");
        // simply pass on that command to the correct script on a server...
        s = Object.FindObjectOfType<Some Class On The Server>();
        s.ClientJumped();
    }
}
```

So!

With new Unity networking, in the client side, every time you want to

```
send to server Jump()
```

you in fact have to send it VIA the "comms" class on the abstract player.

```
public class Jumping: MonoBehavior...

    // here in the client side ... we want to send "Jump"
    Comms comms = Object.FindObjectOfType<Comms>();
    comms.CommandClick1();
```

*(Note - obviously, you would cache the "comms" there. It's just an example.)*

> Aside: extremely important: that is just a outline example.
>
> In
>   practice **you must do this**:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51759299/294884

So!

the thing is this:

in "old" Unity networking, any old client script ***could just directly make a network call*** ("CmdJump" in the example).  All you needed was a link to a NetworkView.

Now you have to have this new "in-between" class, "Comms" in the example.

I am trying to understand,

**is there a way for a normal script on the client side (like Jumping - a MonoBehavior) to directly call a `Command`?**

As far as I know, only `NetworkBehaviour` derived classes can do that. In the old networking, any class could make such a call.

In "new" Unity networking, as far as I know you **must you** pass every call through a `NetworkBehaviour` derived class, as in my example here.

As you can see, if I am "missing something," and the classes such as Jumping can just do it directly, then my code is heinous  :)

Can you call `Command`s directly from in a MonoBehavior?

Am I in fact completely wrong that you have to have the ridiculous auto-spawned "player" objects, and so on?  Maybe there's an entirely other way to call `Command`s.

Comment: My opinion about "**a MonoBehavior to directly call a Command?**" is No, however this doesn't mean that a `NetworkingBehavior` couldn't be subscribed to a Mono event, that will trigger a `[Command]` function.

Comment: Massive bounty here !

Comment: @Hristo, certainly you could use unity events as a convenience (personally I just use a trivial singleton or global to reach the "commas" class).  really though, as you know the point is can you "actually" call a `Command` from a non-NetworkBehaviour ... (like you "used to be able to do" ..)  !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to your question is No. Simply because using the `[Command]` keyword in a `MonoBehavior` will immediately result in an error in your editor, since the code can't be compiled.

> UNetWeaver error: Script XXXXXX uses [Command]
>   YYYYY but is not a NetworkBehaviour.

However there are other possibilities that get very close to what you want to achieve.

- As discussed in the comments, you could use Events and Delegates to subscribe your `[Command]` function to another function from a class that inherits from `MonoBehavior`.
- Another very clever possibility that I have just attempted and had success with is using Interfaces.

I have just made a simple interface that does not implement any other interfaces, it just declares a command. It looks like this:

```
public interface ICustomCommands
{
    [Command]
    void CmdCustomSpawn(GameObject toSpawn);
}
```

Then I made a simple class that will implement this interface (the one method) without using the `[Command]` keyword. **My custom class inherits from `MonoBehavior`** and looks like this:

```
public class CustomCommands : MonoBehaviour, ICustomCommands
{
    public void CmdCustomSpawn(GameObject toSpawn)
    {
        NetworkServer.Spawn(toSpawn);
    }
}
```

I was then successfully able to call my `CmdCustomSpawn` function and spawn a player on the server.

Comment: the interface and the class do not derive from `NetworkBehaviour` .. ??  How can it work ?!  amazing ..

Comment: @Fattie I was flabbergasted myself, have you tried it out?

Comment: Not yet, I have been puzzling  ... maybe the fact that you CAN'T use it in MonoBehavior is one of those "fake" Unity things?  So, they (somehow) "blocked" it, it's not the case that `NetworkBehaviour` is needed.  (Perhaps it just works in a raw base class? I must check!)

Comment: FYI I sent a bounty for this  !   :)

Comment: still investigating!  I need to be 4 people some days  :/  will get back ..